# php exec and shell_exec not working

Tags: php, shell, exec

I want to run an exe file on my server and return the output to the browser screen.
The exe file takes a input file and then returns data on the screen.

Why is this code not working?

```
$output = shell_exec('myprogram < INP.DAT');
echo "<pre>" . var_export($output, TRUE) ."</pre>\\n";
```

It displays "NULL" on the browser screen. I have also tried exec(). There it returns "Array()".

Answer (score 6):

[One of the comments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#87800) on the `shell_exec` manual page says:

> Beware of the following inconsistency: `shell_exec()` and the backtick operator will not return a string if the command's output is empty -- they'll return `NULL` instead.
>
> This will make strict comparisons to `''` return `false`.

---

It may be [disabled if PHP is in safe mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php).

> `shell_exec()` (functional equivalent of backticks)
> This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.
>
> `exec()`
> You can only execute executables within the `safe_mode_exec_dir`. For practical reasons it's currently not allowed to have `..` components in the path to the executable. `escapeshellcmd()` is executed on the argument of this function.

You can check your server's PHP settings with the [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) function.

Comment: Updated, more promising finding

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
$output = array();
exec('myprogram < INP.DAT', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: However, the exec function should fill the $output array with the lines returned from running the shell command so this should work

Answer (score 2):

Is myprogram available from a default shell?  Is it in a specific directory?
Try replacing `myprogram < INP.DAT` with `/full/path/to/myprogram < INP.DAT`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these functions are disabled without the php are in safemode, you have to enable them in php.ini