# display ghostscript version number through PHP in ubuntu

Tags: php, ghostscript

I have written the following code for showing the version number of ghostscript:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?

$ver = shell_exec("/usr/bin/gs --version");
//$ver = exec(GS_BIN . " --version");
print "$ver";
print "A";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get the `A` printed, but not the version number why?

Thanks.

Comment: Try replacing `shell_exec` with `exec`.

Comment: @hakre: Why are you asking me?

Comment: @lokheart: If you execute that command manually in the shell, what does it print on screen? @Rocket: sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly ghostscrsipt is writing the data out to STDERR instead of STDOUT. Try doing

```
/usr/bin/gs --version 2>&1
```

to redirect stderr to stdout and try again

Comment: I need to try the gs version number because I need to use php to use gs to capture some image, but I can't run it using `exec`, so I try a smaller task of showing the version number, but still fail

Comment: @lokheart: Have you tried to redirect STDERR to STDOUT like Marc B suggested?

Comment: i tried `$ver = shell_exec('/usr/bin/gs --version 2>&1');` and the output is `string(111) "/usr/bin/gs: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6) "`, what has gone wrong?

Comment: If gs works from the command line, then whatever shell is being invoked by PHP doesn't have the proper library path, and can't find the gcc library that GS was compiled against.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `var_dump($ver);` for debugging purposes, because your code just works:

```
$ php -r "echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/gs --version');"
8.71
```

I just had it run on my linux box and according to [`shell_exec()` Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), it should be fine.

Things to look for:

- Safe Mode enabled?
- `exec()` can return the exit code / return status of the command.
- if it returns `NULL`, see **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107622/php-exec-and-shell-exec-not-working/1107631#1107631)**.

#### STDERR and shell_exec()

`shell_exec()` will only return the commands output written to STDOUT. In case the command can not be invoked by the shell, this function will return `NULL` and it will hide away what has been reported as error.

To include errors as well in the return value, STDERR needs to be redirect to STDOUT. This is done by adding `2>&1` to the end of the command. Here is the same example code with a wrong command for demonstration:

```
$ php -r "var_dump(shell_exec('/usr/bin/gs2 --version 2>&1'));"
string(44) "sh: /usr/bin/gs2: No such file or directory
"
```

Comment: and I have checked `phpinfo()`, safe mode is disabled

Comment: I added a reference to the question. Check if it helps.